# Attempting to run .Net Framework Web API in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6.2

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Web API I am trying to run in Docker.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  doctorportalapi:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.6.2-20200211-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
    container_name: frameworkapi
    ports:
      - "80:80" # expose 38419 on host and sent to 80 in container
      - "443:443" # expose 38419 on host and sent to 80 in container
      #volumes:
      - ./DoctorPortalAPI/bin:c:/inetpub/wwwroot
```

I can't seem to get any response other than 404 from the site. Is there any other configuration I need to do besides publishing port 80?

I've been able to get a typical website running no problem but not a web api for some reason.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the volume must be set to root folder DoctorPortalAPI

> - ./DoctorPortalAPI:c:/inetpub/wwwroot

This allows the web.config is visible inside the container.